# How to avoid sym.symbols all the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbols

I am trying to use the symbolic libraries of the python Symp. I am getting lots of errors. How to overcome this. every time I don't want to type sym.symobls for defining some thing new.

```
from sympy import *
from math  import *

W1, W2, W3,z1, z2, b, a,g,l = symbols('W1  W2  W3 z1 z2  b a g l')


l = b**2(g/sqrt(a));

#Beam Functions
W1 = simplify(c1*cos(b*x) + c2*sin(b*x) + c3*cosh(b*x) + c4*sinh(b*x));
```

Comment: Use of `import *` is considered bad form; using it multiple times in the same file is an absolute disaster.  In your case, you are overwriting the trig functions from `sympy` (the ones that would *actually work* with the symbols you've defined) with those from `math` (that only work with concrete numbers).  Also, in `b**2(g/sqrt(a))`, you are trying to call `2` as if though it were a function - there's probably a `*` missing there.

Comment: ok, how to write it properly. could you suggest something

Comment: I would suggest never importing `math` if you are working with sympy (at least at this stage) and I would also suggest `from sympy import symbols` if you don't want to write `sym.symbols`.

Comment: @jasonharper, the `isympy` script does use `from sympy import *`, but not any other `*`.  I am used to importing `numpy` as `np`, but for a dedicated `sympy` session this * import doesn't seem to be a problem.  I do agree that importing `math` is unnecessary.  If needed `sympy` uses `mpmath` for numeric calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `l = b**2(g/sqrt(a))` isn't valid. You need e.g. a `*` between the `2` and the opening bracket. Also note that after the assignment, `l` isn't a symbol anymore, but a symbolic expression.

You can avoid declaring many variables by using `sympify()`. That function gets a string as input and creates symbolic variables on the fly.  With `sympify` a lot of standard functions also get their correct symbolic version.

As mentioned in the comments, `from sympy import *` can be problematic, especially if you also work with other libraries.  For convenience, a lot of examples in the docs do use `import *`, but only for short programs which don't use other libraries.

Here is a simple standalone example which assigns a symbolic expression to `l` and shows the internal representation (note that the expression is placed into quotes):

```py
from sympy import sympify, srepr
l = sympify("b**2*(g/sqrt(a))")
print(srepr(l))
W1 = sympify("simplify(c1*cos(b*x) + c2*sin(b*x) + c3*cosh(b*x) + c4*sinh(b*x))")
print(srepr(W1))
```

Output:

```py
Mul(Pow(Symbol('a'), Rational(-1, 2)), Pow(Symbol('b'), Integer(2)), Symbol('g'))

Add(Mul(Symbol('c1'), cos(Mul(Symbol('b'), Symbol('x')))), Mul(Symbol('c2'), sin(Mul(Symbol('b'), Symbol('x')))), Mul(Symbol('c3'), cosh(Mul(Symbol('b'), Symbol('x')))), Mul(Symbol('c4'), sinh(Mul(Symbol('b'), Symbol('x')))))
```

Comment: Is your question answered now? Or is it still open?

Answer (score 0):

Often, routines will allow string input so you can just refer to variables created automatically through `sympify`ing an expression with a string:

```
>>> from sympy import S
>>> S('x')
x
>>> _.subs('x',42)
42
>>> S('2*x').coeff('x')
2
```

If all you are doing is working with single letter symbols and SymPy functions (and no other libraries) you can (and this is how I always start my sessions):

```
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
```

I put the second import there so I get `S` as the shortcut to `sympify` rather than as symbol `S`.